# apply css to li on click without jquery or javascript

Tags: css

here is my html code

```
<div id="menus">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project Manage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Transaction</a></li>
        <li style="border-right:none;"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is my CSS

```
#menus li
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border-right:groove 1px #FFFFFF;
    background: #666666;
}

#menus li:hover
{
    background: #999999;
}

#menus li a
{
    font-size:24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#menus li a:hover
{
    color:#000000;
}
```

now i want to change css when user click on li (like display current selected). can I do this using css only?? If yes then how??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You want it to display as if the user is ON that page? or do you want a:active?

Comment: no sir, you're going to need JS

Comment: Also, the A-tag should have the click event, not the LI.

Comment: @JoshC: exactly that is my point.

Comment: @Diodeus: yeah I know that but i am in search of alternate solutions of it.

Comment: @SohilDesai which one? I listed 2 options. A pseudo-class or class="active", indicating you are ON that page...

Comment: CSS does not have event handlers.

Comment: @JoshC: about user is ON that page.

Comment: @Diodeus: ok so i need to achive that with js or jquery only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with CSS only using `focus` and `tabindex`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/LstNS/4/

```
li:focus  {
  background: red;
  outline: 0;
}
```

A good way to employ an 'active' menu item solution is this

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/LstNS/6/

Source: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200503/setting_the_current_menu_state_with_css/

Comment: Person who downvoted - Please explain, if you downvote an answer at least have the decency to comment

Comment: ah, clever, I was thinking he was meaning when they select the `a`; :)

Comment: @Phil this may not be the way you or i would assign a class to an active menu item but i'm merely answering the question in it's raw form *"apply css to li on click without jquery or javascript"* The question was not *"what's the best way to..."* :)

Comment: @Phil, thanks, i figured you didn't downvote, i was kinda answering two questions at once :/

Comment: LI   is not focusable, even i add tabindex='0', background: red?? only font color was red, in your demo

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not do this with just `css`. I am not too sure what to say...

If you want to have a page specific active, place a different class in the backend, example:

```
<a href="#" class="active"></a>
```